# What do they mean by "natural functor" here?

Tags: category-theory, notation, definition

I'm reading a part of the statement of Yoneda's lemma from Wikipedia.

Yoneda's lemma concerns functors from a fixed category   $\mathcal{C}$ to the category of sets, $\mathcal{Set}$ . If $\mathcal{C}$  is a locally small category (i.e. the hom-sets are actual sets and not proper classes), then each object $A$ of$\mathcal{C}$ gives rise to a natural functor to $Set$ called a hom-functor. This functor is denoted:
$ h^{A} =Hom (A,-).$

In the second last sentence " then each object $A$ of$\mathcal{C}$ gives rise to a natural functor to $Set$", what do they mean by a "natural functor" here?

Is this "natural" mean natural in non-math sense or is "natural functor" a mathematical term for some type of functors? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it's just the non-technical meaning of "natural".